# using the difference between two dates in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter a SELECT query between NOW() and NOW - interval 10 minute(?), but i can't seem to get this to work, and it's given me a few questions on the topic.

I've looked through some documentation online, and alot of questions on stackoverflow but non of the solutions give me what i need. Looking at the TIMEDIFF and TIMESTAMPDIFF documentation, i only see it used like this;

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00');
```

However i don't want to just select the time difference, i want to use it in a query as a WHERE clause, something like;

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (the time difference betweeen NOW() and the stored timestamp is less than x minutes);
```

Is there a particular data type i need to set my column to?
How can i use the TIMEDIFF / TIMESTAMPDIFF correctly, and if these are not the correct methods i should be using, what is?

Comment: So, essentially, you want to know if a date is BETWEEN two other dates?

Comment: In your initial example you're specifying the terms of `BETWEEN` in the wrong order (should be `BETWEEN smallest AND greatest`, are you sure that that's not the problem?

Comment: that was just an example i took from somewhere, but the answers have fixed my problem now. i should have known it would have been something stupidly simple!

Comment: From your second query it must be you want to select rows that has been inserted the last 10 min, right?

Comment: @Shane.C otoh BETWEEN is pretty portable whereas timestamp juggling often isn't...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,timestamp,NOW()) < 10
```

Comment: +1 for to the point *the stored timestamp is less than x minutes*.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE now() - interval 10 minute < stored_timestamp
```

Comment: +1 For keeping the query sargable and not wrapping the timestamp column within a function for comparison.

Comment: @ZaneBien Not sure but I think, for something to be sargable, left part of a condition should not be an expression.

Comment: i've noticed, however (and a bit off-question) that timestamp in mysql is stored in the form "year:month:day hour:minute:second" but C#'s datetime.now() inputs to the database in the form "day:month:year hour:minute:second" Is there a way in SQL to change the format of timestamp?

Comment: @Shane.C: If you use a `prepared statement`then C# will handle the format for you.

Comment: sorry to be a bother again. i've got it to input into the database in the correct format, using timestamp as the field type. However the query seems not to work anymore, looking for less than 10 minutes returns nothing, but looking for greater than 10 returns all rows, even though less than 10 minutes?

Comment: @Shane.C: You actually don't need to pass the C# datetime to yor query. SQL itself has a `NOW()` function like in my query above. That way you don't need a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subtract current time - column time and fetch those records who are less than and equal to 30 seconds, then use below query

```
select * from table_name WHERE NOW() - timnameestamp_column  <= 30
```